# KDE Kile + Okular forward search

Tags: kubuntu, kde, okular, kile

I have just successfully managed to set up inverse search between Kile and Okular using [this guide](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/extragear-office/kile/quick_inverse.html). Right next to it there is an even shorter [guide](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/extragear-office/kile/quick_forward.html) about forward search.

Given that inverse search already works then this 'guide' essentially boils down to saying that I should 'click Forward Search', my question is: where is 'Forward Search' in Kile? There is no button like that anywhere, the right-click menu does not have this option and neither do the top and bottom toolbars. I am using Kile 2.1.3 together with KDE platform 4.13.3.